# How to detect loop closure after scan matching?

Tags: laser

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
How to detect loop closures from the scan matched 2D data?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/272231/how-to-detect-loop-closure-after-scan-matching?/) by [Raksha Murthy](https://answers.ros.org/users/32140/raksha-murthy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-10-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a non-trivial problem, two approaches doing this are implemented in [open_karto](https://github.com/ros-perception/open_karto) and [cartographer](https://github.com/googlecartographer/cartographer). For the latter, you can read about the clever branch-and-bound approach used in [this paper](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=1316991902388640452&hl=en).

In gmapping, there is no explicit detection of loop closures, but map hypotheses with "badly" matched parts get a low weight and get sampled out.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2017-10-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Raksha Murthy](https://answers.ros.org/users/32140/raksha-murthy/) on 2017-10-09**:
May i know how to solve using open_karto? Could you please elaborate the steps? What are the changes to be made in tha launch files to run my own datasets?